# click event using d3

Tags: events, d3.js, click

Good day, I have a simple d3 code that, is there a way to know if the user click on the array of choices in my html text

here is my code

```
 d3.csv("data/gridview.csv", function (data) {
        d3.select("div")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
           .on("click", function (d) { alert("Sample");})
            .append("div")
        .html(function (d) { return +d.Value + '<br />' + d.Name; })
        console.log(data)

    });
```

my gridview has 3 records inside to once i run my application the records will show on the page. my problem is that once the user click on the first row i want to show line graph of it, same as second row and third row..

is there a way how to do it..

Comment: You're already attaching a click handler to those elements. Anything you want to happen on click needs to go in there.

Comment: i mean i have 3 element inside div. if i click on the first element i want to view the line graph of that element same as the second and the third but the element are different..

Comment: You can attach click handlers to those other `div`s in the same way you're attaching it to the first.